# Removing array from another array based on checkbox check

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, arrays, checkbox

I have a html table with checkbox in each rows. On checking each checkbox I'm pushing the row values to an array named `checkboxArrayForOperations`.

**HTML**

```
<table>
<?php
$i = 0;
foreach ($databaseValue as $stValue) {
$i++;
?>
<tr>
    <input type="text" id="stName<?php echo $i;?>" value="<?php echo $stValue['stName'];?>">
    <input type="text" id="stId<?php echo $i;?>" value="<?php echo $stValue[0]['stId'];?>">
    <td><input type="checkbox" class="checkboxForOperations" value="<?php echo $i;?>" onclick="checkBoxForOperations(this)"></td>
</tr>
<?php
}
?>
</table>
```

**JS**

```
var checkboxArrayForOperations = []; // global array
function checkBoxForOperations(obj){
    var checkboxValue =  obj.value;
    if(obj.checked) {
        checkboxArray = [];
        checkboxArray["stName"] = $('#stName'+checkboxValue).val();
        checkboxArray["stId"] = $('#stId'+checkboxValue).val();
        checkboxArrayForOperations.push(checkboxArray);

    } else {
        var itemArrayForRemoval = [];
        itemArrayForRemoval["stName"] = $('#stName'+checkboxValue).val();
        itemArrayForRemoval["stId"] = $('#stId'+checkboxValue).val();
        var indexItemArrayForRemoval = index(itemArrayForRemoval);

        checkboxArrayForOperations = checkboxArrayForOperations.filter( function( el ) {
          return !(JSON.stringify(el) in itemArrayForRemoval);
        } );

    }
    console.log(checkboxArrayForOperations);
} 

function index(arr) {
    return arr.reduce(function(acc, item){
        return acc[JSON.stringify(item)] = item, acc
    }, {})    
}
```

On uncheck I want to remove the elements (added as array) corresponding to that unchecked row. I'm referring this [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/26635593/2256771). But the array is not getting removed from `checkboxArrayForOperations`. The array looks like shown in [JSFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/w1rgthas/)

What am I doing wrong? Can anyone help me to fix this. Thanks in advance.

Comment: Are you basically trying to add the value of the checkbox to the array when you click a checkbox and then remove it when you uncheck it?

Comment: @GrahamS. I'm saving the stname and stid values corresponding to checked row to the array.

Comment: Cool, and you're ultimately trying to send all the checked data to the server, right?

Comment: @GrahamS..Yes. On unchecking I want to delete the data corresponding to that row if it was already added (already checked).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'd suggest to change your table format, if it's possible. Moreover, you don't have an array of array, and so I'd suggest you to consider an array of objects.

A possible solution could be:

```js
var checkboxArrayForOperations = []; // global array
function checkCheckBoxForOperations(obj) {
    var checkboxValue = obj.value;
    if (obj.checked) {
        checkboxArray = [];
        checkboxArrayForOperations.push({"stName":  $('#stName' + checkboxValue).val(),
                "stId": $('#stId' + checkboxValue).val()});

    } else {
        var itemArrayForRemoval = {"stName":  $('#stName' + checkboxValue).val(),
                "stId": $('#stId' + checkboxValue).val()};

        checkboxArrayForOperations = checkboxArrayForOperations.filter(function (el, index) {
            return JSON.stringify(el) != JSON.stringify(itemArrayForRemoval);
        });

    }
    console.log(checkboxArrayForOperations);
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>


<table>
    <tbody>
    <tr>
        <td>
            <input type="text" id="stName1" value="1">
        </td>
        <td>
            <input type="text" id="stId1" value="1">
        </td>
        <td><input type="checkbox" class="checkboxForOperations" value="1" onclick="checkCheckBoxForOperations(this)"></td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td>
            <input type="text" id="stName2" value="2">
        </td>
        <td>
            <input type="text" id="stId2" value="2">
        </td>
        <td><input type="checkbox" class="checkboxForOperations" value="2" onclick="checkCheckBoxForOperations(this)"></td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td>
            <input type="text" id="stName3" value="3">
        </td>
        <td>
            <input type="text" id="stId3" value="3">
        </td>
        <td><input type="checkbox" class="checkboxForOperations" value="3" onclick="checkCheckBoxForOperations(this)"></td>
    </tr>
    </tbody>
</table>
```

Answer (score 0):

Have you looked in the console what might be wrong, I can see this:

> index.html:41 Uncaught ReferenceError: checkBoxForOperations is not defined
>       at HTMLInputElement.onclick

Try renaming in the HTML to "checkCheckBoxForOperations" instead of "checkBoxForOperations".

Answer (score 0):

You can use object literal instead of array to assign a key as identifier to remove the item:

```
var checkboxArrayForOperations = {}; // global object
function checkBoxForOperations(obj){
    var checkboxValue =  obj.value;
    if(obj.checked) {
        var checkboxArray = {};
        checkboxArray["stName"] = $('#stName'+checkboxValue).val();
        checkboxArray["stId"] = $('#stId'+checkboxValue).val();
        checkboxArrayForOperations["stId"] = checkboxArray;

    } else {
        var itemArrayForRemoval = $('#stId'+checkboxValue).val();
        if(checkboxArrayForOperations.hasOwnProperty(itemArrayForRemoval)){
           delete checkboxArrayForOperations[itemArrayForRemoval];
        }    
    }
}
```

And if you still need values in array, you can use below code:

```
var finalArray = [];
    for(var i in checkboxArrayForOperations){
        finalArray[finalArray.length] = checkboxArrayForOperations[i];
    }
```

Comment: ..I can't assign any key as identifier to the array as both stid and stname are not unique.